# How to access hours in a python datetime.time column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe:

```
TRADE_DATE TICKET_TIME GATE_ENTRY_TIME GATE_EXIT_TIME
2016-09-23    18:00:27        18:02:28       18:55:35
2016-09-23    18:08:48        18:09:01       18:31:11
2016-09-23    19:05:33        19:06:33       19:41:43 
2016-09-23    18:06:55        18:08:42       18:34:41
2016-09-23    10:31:35        10:32:06       10:47:27
```

I want to create a new column by extracting the hours from the datetime.time values in column TICKET_TIME.

I have tried df['HOUR'] = df['TICKET_TIME'].dt.hour, but it didn't work:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Comment: Are you sure that the values in the `TICKET_TIME` column are `datetime` objects and not strings? (Perhaps try printing `type(df.loc[0,"TICKET_TIME"])` first )

Comment: Try pandas.to_datetime(df['TICKET_TIME'], errors = 'coerce')

Comment: They are datetime.time object. If I use pandas.to_datetime(df['TICKET_TIME'], errors = 'coerce') again, they became NaT.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use list comprehension if working with `time`s:

```
print (type(df.loc[0,"TICKET_TIME"]))
<class 'datetime.time'>

df['Hour'] = [x.hour for x in df['TICKET_TIME']]
```

Alternative solution:

```
df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TICKET_TIME'].astype(str)).dt.hour
```

---

```
print (df)
   TRADE_DATE TICKET_TIME GATE_ENTRY_TIME GATE_EXIT_TIME  Hour
0  2016-09-23    18:00:27        18:02:28       18:55:35    18
1  2016-09-23    18:08:48        18:09:01       18:31:11    18
2  2016-09-23    19:05:33        19:06:33       19:41:43    19
3  2016-09-23    18:06:55        18:08:42       18:34:41    18
4  2016-09-23    10:31:35        10:32:06       10:47:27    10
```